# Nuget "This method is not supported by this class"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm having problems to connect to a private Nuget repository. Everything worked well until today but out of the sudden I'm getting the following error when trying to browse the repository via Visual Studio:

> [XYZArtifactory] Unable to load the service index for source
> https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/nuget/XXX-nuget-local/.
> An error occurred while sending the request.
> The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
> This method is not supported by this class.

I'm using VS2019 16.7 and the 16.8 Preview. Connecting to the artifactory server via UI works well and I see that there still are packages in the repository. Nothing was changed on the server since last week but my system had an Windows update since then...

I tried to remove the source and credentials from nuget.config and win credential manager and added it again with no change.

Any ideas what error can cause this message?

Comment: I think it's very unlikely that there is a version problem. Nuget and Artifactory versions where not changed lately. I'm using NuGet via .net cli at version 5.8.0.4 and the Artifactory version is 7.3.2.

Comment: Enter `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `detailed` and then try again to check the detailed log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not sure** whether the windows update affects the connection between your network and the nuget server or the `SSL/TLS`.

**First**, you should enter the path `https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/nuget/XXX-nuget-local/` on your website to check whether you can access it. And if not, the issue is related to your network and you should check on your network very carefully.

If it can access, then, you could try the following suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

**2)** disable any third party vs installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

**3)** open VS-->**Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console** and then type:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

**4)** delete the global `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` or other custom `nuget.config`, then restart VS, and then readd the info into that file.

**5)** If your VS has any updates, please update it.

**6)** enter **Settings**(Global Settings of your PC)-->**Network and Internet**-->**Proxy**-->**Automatic Proxy Setup**-->set **Automatically detect settings** to `off`.

**Then**,

add [nuget Proxy setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section) under nuget.config file.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer and sorry for that late reply. I solved this issue earlier by deleting the nuget.config file. I'm not sure what was wrong with the old one since I wasn't able to identify any syntax errors. Deleting that source and readding it didn't solved it though.
I think SSL/TLS errors would led to a less generic error message. I still don't know what method and class is meant in the message...